# Using probability to detect exam cheating (identical wrong answers)

Tags: probability

Hypothetical:  What’s the probability that two people taking a test with 10 questions get the identical wrong answers?  (Let's say there are 4 choices per problem)

Should we first break this down into asking "What are the odds of getting the same questions wrong?"

Also, would it be easier to first use the number incorrect as a constant?  ie:   What’s the probability that two people taking a test with 10 questions get THREE identical wrong answers? (and the other 7 correct)

Comment: Are these people guessing each answer at random?

Comment: One of my undergrad professors gave us a final paper instead of an exam. And he said that in the event that all the papers handed will have the same answers he is going to assume this is a highly improbable-but not impossible sort of event.

Comment: If all students wrongly answer that the Earth is flat, it may not be a case of cheating but of bad teaching ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether one person gets a question wrong or right, the other has to get the same answer. If the answer was wrong, the second person needs to get the same answer to fit the condition that they get the same wrong answers. If the answer was right, the second person needs to get it right as well; otherwise, he would have answered a question wrong that the first person answered right.

Using this logic, the probability of the condition holding for a one-question test is $\frac{1}{4}$. So, for x amount of questions, the probability would be $\frac{1}{4^x}$. And we can generalize this result further by declaring the number of choices for each question to be y. Then the probability of the condition holding is $\frac{1}{y^x}$.

Comment: What a perfect example of restating the premise!  I was barking up the wrong tree until you cleared the mist and restated the question as, "What are the odds they select all the same answers"  This is a much simple probability problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As it has been mentioned already, the problem is ill-posed and the answer can be any number from $0$ to $1$ depending on the situation. I am writing it just to state it explicitly. The extreme points are

Great Inquisitor (year 13..): Here are 4 cosmology questions. Your verdict will depend on what answers you choose (close to $1$)

Teacher (any year you want): Last time you were caught cheating. If you both submit the same wrong answer again, I'll raise the question about expelling you both from the school!
(close to $0$)

"Close to" rather than "=" because the assumption that human intelligence is greater than human stubbornness is dubious. :-)

The intermediate points are like:

What nation invented the compass?
1) Americans
2) Chinese
3) Babylonians
4) Klingonese

Comment: Nice example. Any reasonable person should give one of two answers, so all wrong answers should be identical.

Comment: What's interesting is that most multiple choice quizzes are just like that, except when the teacher takes special effort to hide the right answer or does a nasty thing of the kind $\sqrt 7$ is closest to a) 2.6456 b) 2.6457 c) 2.6458 d) 2.6459 (to which any normal person should just respond "and who would care remembering it with this precision or seeing one of them as any different from the other three?") :-)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here is wrong.  You cannot simply multiply probabilities of A and B to find the probability of A AND B unless these events are independent and uncorrelated, which is not generally true for test questions.  Looking at test results will generally show that all answers are not chosen with equal likelihood.  Even if that weren't true, any two questions on an exam could be highly correlated -- they might both depend on the same information or assumptions.  Also, any two students answering otherwise uncorrelated questions might be highly correlated -- especially identical twins living in a bubble.  In short, you can't answer the question without detailed information about the test and the students.

The accepted answer is right for the question only if you assume the students chose completely at random, a very unrealistic assumption.

I hope people will stop and take a moment to think about this more.  The title of this is "Using probability to detect cheating".  There are probably teachers falsely accusing students of cheating based on their confidence in the credibility of math.stackexchange, and this wrong answer.  It is possible using naive approaches to detect cheating in very extreme cases, but otherwise it requires very sophisticated techniques.  This isn't it.

Comment: Answers are uncorrelated.  If you study randomness, AAAAA is just as probable as ABCDE or ACBED.

Comment: To understand my point, answer this.  What if 90% of the test-takers choose the first multiple choice answer for question 1.  How can this choice have a 1/4 probability as I the accepted answer says?  Isn't it 9/10 probability?  And if 100% of people who chose that answer, also choose the first answer for the second question, that combination has at least a 9/10 probability, not 1/4 * 1/4.